# TouchableOpacity hides the content of a View during onPress

Tags: css, react-native, touchableopacity

I'm trying to create a button component which looks like this.

[image]

The TouchableOpacity component is wrapped inside a LinearGradient component. When I touch the button, the inner view stars to have a very low opacity. I'm understood that this is one of the features of TouchableOpacity but is there a way to disable it?

I've played with the props **activeOpacity** and **focusedOpacity** but its still render improperly.

Here's the code

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';

import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

import em from './../../styles/calculateSize';

const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const GradientButton = ({ propStyle, buttonText, onPress }) => {
  const { centerEverything, buttonGradientStyle, buttonStyle, buttonTextStyle } = styles;
  return (
    <LinearGradient colors={['#FF7676', '#F54EA2']} style={[buttonGradientStyle, centerEverything]}>
      <TouchableOpacity 
        style={[buttonStyle, centerEverything]} 
        activeOpacity={1} 
        focusedOpacity={1}
        onPress={onPress}>
        <Text style={buttonTextStyle}>{buttonText}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </LinearGradient>
  );
}

const styles = {
  centerEverything: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonGradientStyle: {
    height: 27,
    width: deviceWidth * 0.23,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginLeft: 5
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    height: 24,
    width: deviceWidth * 0.23 - 3,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    opacity: 0.1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: 3,
  },
  buttonTextStyle: {
    fontSize: em(0.75),
    color: '#F54EA2',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  }
}

export { GradientButton };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to discover the correct method of what I am trying to achieve here, thanks to **Christian Tucker** on the **Facebook React Native Community.**

Essentially to remove the visual effect TouchableOpacity renders, I need to use TouchableWithoutFeedback, to which I have already known in the first place.

Second, this component structure would still render error even if I replace TouchableOpacity with TouchableWithoutFeedback.

- LinearGradient

  - TouchableWithoutFeedback

This is the correct approach

```js
return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
      <LinearGradient colors={['#FF7676', '#F54EA2']} style={[buttonGradientStyle, centerEverything]}>
        <View style={[buttonStyle, centerEverything]} >
          <Text style={buttonTextStyle}>{buttonText}</Text>
        </View>
      </LinearGradient>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
```